# Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 96, 11), found shape=(32, 11)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to write my very first machine learning program by using `tensorflo`w. I was following this YouTube tutorial and decided to use a different dataset. This is the error message that I'm keep getting:

> Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer:
> expected shape=(None, 96, 11), found shape=(32, 11)

I have no idea how to solve it.

This is the info of my dataset:

> RangeIndex: 121 entries, 0 to 120 Data columns (total 12 columns):  #
> Column
> Non-Null Count  Dtype
>
> ---
>
> 0   1. Your Gender
> 121 non-null    int64
>
> 1   2. Your Age
> 121 non-null    int64
>
> 2   5. How often do you visit Starbucks?
> 121 non-null    int64
>
> 3   9. Do you have Starbucks membership card?
> 121 non-null    int64
>
> 4   12. How would you rate the quality of Starbucks compared to other
> brands (Coffee Bean, Old Town White Coffee..) to be:  121 non-null
> int64
>
> 5   13. How would you rate the price range at Starbucks?
> 121 non-null    int64
>
> 6   14. How important are sales and promotions in your purchase
> decision?                                                   121
> non-null    int64
>
> 7   15. How would you rate the ambiance at Starbucks? (lighting,
> music, etc...)                                             121
> non-null    int64
>
> 8   16. You rate the WiFi quality at Starbucks as..
> 121 non-null    int64
>
> 9   17. How would you rate the service at Starbucks? (Promptness,
> friendliness, etc..)                               121 non-null
> int64
>
> 10  18. How likely you will choose Starbucks for doing business
> meetings or hangout with friends?                           121
> non-null    int64
>
> 11  20. Will you continue buying at Starbucks?    121 non-null
> int64
>
> dtypes: int64(12)
>
> memory usage: 11.5 KB

```
#split the data into a training set and a testing set
#using train_test_split from sklearn.model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2)

import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = x_train.shape)
hidden_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu')
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')
model = tf.keras.Sequential([input_layer, hidden_layer, output_layer])

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'Adam')

model.summary()

tf.reshape(x_train, [96, 11])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=600)
```

This is the the entire code I wrote

```
x = df.drop(columns = ["20. Will you continue buying at Starbucks?"])

y = df["20. Will you continue buying at Starbucks?"]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2)
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = x_train.shape[1])
hidden_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu')
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')
model = tf.keras.Sequential([input_layer, hidden_layer, output_layer])

model.summary()

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=600)
```

Comment: Your colab link is not working. By the way, try this `input_shape = x_train.shape[1]`, and also remove that `tf.reshape` line.

Comment: oh, oops! I just edit my question and added the entire code

Comment: oh my god, it worked!! thank you so much angel♡